# Expand nested arrays postgres

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, nested, jsonb

I have a jsonb column, progress, on a table (call it t). It has data like this:

```
{
    "2": {
        "8": "completed",
        "9": "completed",
        "10": "completed",
        "percent_completed": 0
    },
    "5": {
        "40": "completed",
        "percent_completed": 0
    }
}
```

I'm trying to get a table that looks like:

```
Top Level | Send Level | status
-------------------------------
| 2       | 8          | completed
| 2       | 9          | completed
| 2       | 10         | completed
| 5       | 40         | completed
```

I am struggling to get a statement that works. I'm almost there (I can get the top level column), but I can't get the second level. This works to extract the first key:

```
    select top_level
        , progress
    from t
        cross join jsonb_object_keys(progress) top_level
```

When I then try to get the second level, it doesn't work. I am struggling to answer why:

```
    select top_level
        , second_level
        , t
    from t
        cross join jsonb_object_keys(progress) top_level
        cross join jsonb_object_keys(progress->top_level) second_level
```

I get the following error: `ERROR: cannot call jsonb_object_keys on a scalar`

I'm using Postgres 11.8

I have tried different json operators and casting the resulting data in a bunch of different ways, but I am struggling to figure it out. Would really appreciate the help.

Comment: I don't think you can reference the top_level in the second join because the query engine doesn't know what you mean.

Comment: Looking at https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-json.html it looks like you might try `#>` as it gets the JSON Object and not the JSON Object Field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `jsonb_each()` and `jsonb_each_text()` instead of `jsonb_object_keys()`:

```
select 
    t1.key as top_level, 
    t2.key as send_level,
    t2.value as value
from t
cross join jsonb_each(progress) as t1
cross join jsonb_each_text(t1.value) as t2
where t2.key <> 'percent_completed'
```

[Db<>fiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=40383501702f8103c0fd2ddf6e168ac4)

Read in the documentation about [JSON Functions and Operators.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html)

Comment: Thank you so much for the help klin!